# this.activatedRoute.params is undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have routing in `app-routing.module.ts` I want to get playerId and teamId from the router but it returns undefined in the console as I subscribe to it in AppComponent.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(map((p) => p['teamId'])).subscribe((param) => console.log(param)); //undefined
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: 'teams', component: TeamsListComponent },
  { path: 'teams/:teamId', component: TeamDetailComponent },
  { path: 'teams/:teamId/players', component: PlayersListComponent },
  { path: 'teams/:teamId/players/:playerId', component: PlayerDetailComponent },
  { path: 'players', component: PlayersListComponent },
  { path: 'players/:playerId', component: PlayerDetailComponent },
];
```

The url: `http://localhost:4291/teams/t1/players/p2`

Comment: is there a reason that you need the params from app component? i am pretty sure you will get those ids in the PlayerListCompnent and PlayerDetailComponent.

Comment: I need the params such as `playerId` and `teamId` in some other components too. Maybe I can store it in the store. For that reason I wanted to listen the changes.

Comment: you might want to use Router for this then. it has a observable called events. And you can check for NavgiationEnd event and get them from there, as one solution. https://angular.io/api/router/Router#properties